# Spring Pageable in handler

Tags: spring, pagination

I have a handler like this:

```
@GetMapping("/users")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>> getAllUsers(@ApiParam Pageable pageable) {
    log.debug("REST request to get a page of Users");
    Page<UserDTO> page = userService.findAll(pageable);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/users");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

It was generated by JHipster. My main issue with this is that i dont understand what the front end is supposed to send to match `Pageable` object.

This handler will should return paginated users based on search words submitted by the user. I am using mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [github issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/1920) it states

> The custom pagable parameters (limit, offset) are replaced to the
>   Spring custom argument resolver PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver

You can find the code for PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/web/PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java). The default parameter names are "page" and "size". You might want to take a look at the [jhipster-sample-app-mongodb](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-mongodb) which does look to showcase pagination. Example can be found [here](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-mongodb/blob/c95180328fc26c3b4bc3bb40540e1354a66a0e79/src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management.controller.js)